# Redirecting stdout to stdin in POSIX C

Tags: c, io, posix

I am trying to write a program that redirects `stdout` into `stdin`, mostly to better understand how `dup2()` works. I tried writing a simple program that would make it so that if you `printf()` something, you can later `scanf()` it back, but didn't manage to get it to work. First I tried just using `dup2(0, 1)`, thinking it would redirect `stdout` (1) to `stdin` (0). This didn't work. I thought that since one is used for input and the other for output they might not be compatible, so I tried using a pipe to do this, like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
    int pipe_desc[2];
    pipe(pipe_desc);
    dup2(pipe_desc[0], 0);
    dup2(pipe_desc[1], 1);
    printf("foo");
    char bar[20];
    scanf("%s", bar);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s", bar);
}
```

However, now even though `printf`, as I understand it, was supposed to put `"foo"` into the pipe, when I call `scanf`, the program just hangs there, and reads neither from stdin, nor from the pipe. What is wrong? What exactly happens in this code? Can such redirection be done without pipes (or any other helper structures for that matter)?

Comment: You seem to forget that output to `stdout` by default is *line buffered*. Either explicitly `fflush` the buffer, or add a trailing newline to the string you print.

Comment: `scanf` reads *space-delimited strings*. stdin is *buffered*... those 2 perhaps. Try writing `printf("foo\n");`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude line buffered if connected to a terminal. Here, probably even fully...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Probably true. However I'd say it depends on how lazy the stdio system is, if the file is opened and buffering set up on program starting, or when the first output operation is done.

Comment: I don't think it is usually set up before the first op because of `setvbuf`

Comment: `fflush` is definitely needed.  `stdout` should be line buffered when pointing to a terminal, and when pointing to a pipe or file it should be even *more* aggressively buffered.  Whether it remains line buffered after being changed isn't clear, but in *either* case `fflush` is needed, given that `"foo"` doesn't end in a newline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How your works, explanation is there in the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
        int pipe_desc[2];
        pipe(pipe_desc);
        printf("pid = %d \n",getpid());
        /* above statement creates 2 descriptors 3 & 4. 3 is for read and 4 is for write**/
        dup2(pipe_desc[0], 0);
        /** 3 is duplicates with 0(stdin) i.e if you try to do scanf, it won't scan from keyboard, it will scan from pipe(read end, for that make sure something should be there in pipe  **/
        dup2(pipe_desc[1], 1);
        /** 4 is duplicates with 1 (stdout) i.e if you try to write onto screen, it won't. It will try into pipe write end **/
        /** SO TILL NOW FD DETAILS
                0,3 --> PIPE_DESC[0]
                1,4 --> PIPE_DESC[1] 
        **/
        #if 1
        fflush(stdout);
        printf("foo\n");//it won't print 
        char bar[20];
        scanf("%s", bar);//it won't scan bcz 0 is poiting to pipe_desc[0]
        #endif
        /** YOU CAN CHECK USING OTHER TERMINAL "ls -l /proc/pid/fd/" **/

        fprintf(stderr, "%s", bar);// fd 2 is still available.So foo gets printed on screen
}
```

open another terminal while above program is running, view the fd details using

```
root@xyz-PC:/home/achal/s_flow/cpp# ls -l /proc/4503/fd
total 0
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Jan 15 16:45 0 -> pipe:[782489]
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Jan 15 16:45 1 -> pipe:[782489]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan 15 16:45 2 -> /dev/pts/9
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Jan 15 16:45 3 -> pipe:[782489]
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Jan 15 16:45 4 -> pipe:[782489]
```